# printwriter is considering only one slash instead of double slash in the hdfs path

Tags: scala, hadoop, printwriter

My Code is :

```
 val df = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
       .option("rowTag", header)
       .load("/input/du3_init.dat")
 val dfCI2 = df.select("CI2")
 dfCI2.printSchema()
 val path="hdfs://nameservice/user/CI2_Schema"
 new PrintWriter(path) { write(dfCI2.schema.treeString);close}
```

When I execute in spark, I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/nameservice/user/CI2_Schema (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
```

Only one slash is present in the hdfs path shown in the exception. How to resolve this?. Thanks in advance

Comment: `PrintWriter` is not supposed to understand network paths such as those with `hdfs://` or `ftp://`. Its works with local file system. And in local filesystem paths are of format `a/b/c`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write to `hdfs`, you can not use `PrintWriter`. PrintWriter is not supposed to understand network paths such as those with `hdfs://` or `ftp://`. It works with the local file system.

You can write to `hdfs` by getting the `hdfs` configuration form spark context.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream


val hdfsConf = sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration

val fileSystem: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf)

val filePath = "hdfs://nameservice1/user/dhdpbankcrtbtch/CIW2_Schema"

val hdfsFileOS: FSDataOutputStream = fileSystem.create(new Path(filePath));

// create a buffered output stream using the FSDataOutputStream
val bos = new BufferedOutputStream(hdfsFileOS)

bos.write(dfCIW2.schema.treeString.toBytes("utf-8"))

bos.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sarvesh.